# NSLayoutConstraint for UITableViewCell: Constraint must contain a first layout item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to set `NSLayoutConstraint` within each of my custom cells (inherited from `UITableViewCell`), rather than specifying them in a `UIViewController` to avoid cluttering it by exposing the constraints for each cell type.

The problem is that I could not find an appropriate part of the cell's lifecycle to create the layout constraints (I tried `layoutSubviews()` and `awakeFromNib()`), but they all get called too early in the cell's lifecycle, when its `superview` has not been defined yet - it results in this error:

> Constraint must contain a first layout item

Since `UITableViewCell` does not have the `viewDidLoad()` method like the `UIViewController`, how is it possible to define the layout constraints within the cell?

`layoutSubviews()` of the custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.attributeNameLabel
                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem: self.contentView
                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                 multiplier: 1
                                   constant: 3] setActive:true];
    [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.attributeNameLabel
                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem: self.contentView
                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                 multiplier: 1
                                   constant: 3] setActive:true];
    [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.attributeNameLabel
                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem: self.contentView
                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                 multiplier: 1
                                   constant: 3] setActive:true];
    [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.attributeNameLabel
                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                  relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem: self.contentView
                                  attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 multiplier: 1
                                   constant: 3] setActive:true];   
}
```

Example initialization in `UIViewController`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)view cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell = [[CustomCell1 alloc] init];
    } else if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
        cell = [[CustomCell2 alloc] init];
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you are not using xib or storyboard?

Comment: I'd prefer not to use storyboard, because I have many different cell types (with inheritance and so on) ... it would quickly get messy

Comment: have you tried updateConstraintsIfNeeded() after setting the constraints?

Comment: No I can't, the app doesn't even set the first constraint. It crashes at this line: `[[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:...`

Comment: Try using anchors. It's much more cleaner. See [here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/)

Answer (score 2):

try to make

```
 self.attributeNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

for every label not the contentView

convert them like that it worked for me

do this

```
  - (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code



[super awakeFromNib];


UILabel*ddd = [UILabel new];

ddd.text = @"adsbcujklasdcbaksci";

ddd.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;

[self.contentView addSubview:ddd];

 NSLayoutConstraint*ss1 =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: ddd
                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem: self.contentView
                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             multiplier: 1 constant: 3] ;
NSLayoutConstraint*ss2 =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: ddd
                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem: self.contentView
                              attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                             multiplier: 1   constant: 3]  ;

 [self.contentView addConstraints:@[ss1,ss2]];



 [self layoutSubviews];

 [self layoutIfNeeded];



}
```

Comment: What would be the required elements in this case? I'm only accessing `self.contentView` and `self.attributeNameLabel` in this example, but still getting error about missing first layout item.

Comment: add the above two lines at the end of your function

Comment: This alone doesn't work, same error. Btw I am not having problems calling the `layoutSubviews()`. It gets called automatically without adding it to the end of the function.

Comment: This works, I have to look at it closely before accepting the answer.